# Typescript: Add extra one hour to timestamp

Tags: javascript, typescript, time

How can I add exta 1hour to a timestamp

for example,  `1574620200000 (With Micro Seconds)`

this is my date in the format of timestamp, can i add a number with the timestamp to increase time to extra 1 hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add `60 * 60 * 1000` ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could add `(60*60*1000)` with your time

> ```
> 1 sec = 1000 ms
> 1 min = 60 sec
> 1 hr  = 60 min
> ```

```js
const t = new Date();
t.setTime(1574620200000+(60*60*1000));

console.log(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes an **hour** in **microseconds** is equal to `3600000000`, so all you have to do is add that **hour** in microseconds to the existing **time**,

```
var time = 1574620200000;
var hour = 3600000000;
var newTime = time + hour;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you're working with `Date`s is using `getHours()` and `setHours()`:

```
const now = new Date();
console.log(now);
now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1);
console.log(now);
```